# Getting text from dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

When I select an item, I want to just get the text. How can I do it?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dropd" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="text1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="text2"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="text3"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="text4"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You May use

```
dropd.SelectedItem.Text
```

At which event you want to get selected text value of dropdown means at PageLoad or at Dropdown SelectedIndexChanged.If you want on SelectedIndexChanged then set **AutoPostBack** property of dropdown to **True**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropd" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
       <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="text1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="text2"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="text3"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="text4"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

**CODE:-**

```
protected void dropd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string Getvalue = dropd.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```